# How to View Windows Files on a Wubi install?

Tags: 11.10, windows, wubi, files

I wanted to ask, how can i view all my windows files on Ubuntu. I found out how to get my D drive folders but have yet not figured out how to get my **C drive** files. Please give me an easy way to find my files. For more information, i have installed ubuntu via wubi. Please answer my question ASAP.

Answer (score 12):

In a Wubi install your windows partition (your C: drive) is mounted in */host/*

In nautilus, the file manager, click on the File System icon at the left bar. In the right panel there is view with some folders, all your C: drive contents will be inside of the one called **host**.

Comment: Thnx but i want my C drive contents

Comment: If C is the drive where windows is installed your contents should be accessible as I said.

Comment: Thank you so much.  Do you know if I can configure this to be readonly?

Comment: I don't think so. I don't really understand how /host works (it's mounted at boot time, but not in fstab), but the Ubuntu image is contained in it. It's likely that a read-only host means a read-only Ubuntu. But as I said I don't really understand how it works.

Answer (score 4):

To explore your harddisks you can use `Disk Utility`. Open the Dash with the <kbd>Windows</kbd>-key and type in *disk*... and start the application.

[image: open disk utility]

On the left hand you find your *Storage Devices*. Choose the right one. Now you can mount the proper volume (if not yet done) on the right hand (*Mount Volume*) and open the folder by clicking the path shown under *Mount Point*.

Be careful with options like *Format Drive*, *Edit Partition*, and *Delete Partition!* You could lose data or damage your system.

You should be able to find your user data under *(C)/Users/(Username)/...* (**Documents**, **Music**, etc.)

Comment: As this is a wubi install, the volume should be already mounted. But anyway, this is a great idea, it appears there as mounted and the link works.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu, open Nautilus and navigate to the root of the file system( default open location should be /home/home, just navigate back to /)

After, open the directory called "host". It is C: directory from Windows.