# problem in finding the lsystem file drive in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: installation, dual-boot, mount

am new to linux/ubuntu. mayb finding it difficult to access all the features . i have dual booted ubuntu 12.04 along with windows 7 using WUBI.the installation is done in separate  drive G: where the windiws is in Drive C: i started ubuntu 12.04 after reboot everythng works fine and showing all the drives alongwith Drive G .after i unmounted the drive from the desktop panel to get rid of the unneccesary drive list . now i could not find it in HOME FOLDER drive list. showing all the drives after unmounting but the Drive G is not found.tried to look into some tutorials but no success.and 1 more thing i can see the config files of windows like desktop.ini in all the drives which i think is hidden from using windows. what happen if i delete the file from ubuntu desktop.ini. will it affect windows later?
 thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you install Ubuntu using wubi, the drive on which it is mounted is `/host/`. You should see that on the left hand side panel in nautilus. All the files in your `G: drive` would be here, in `/host/`.

Secondly, the `desktop.ini` file is the file that contains all windows settings for the particular directory. If you delete this file, all settings pertaining to that directory will be lost and default settings will be loaded for that directory. Settings here mean the "View", "icon types", etc.

**Source:**

- [Where can I view Windows files on a Wubi install?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/113172/how-to-view-windows-files-on-a-wubi-install)
- [What is the desktop.ini file and can I delete it?](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001060.htm)